# SELECT STATEMENT WITH SUBQUERIES

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have the following select. It makes a call to separate DB's to gather all of the info required. Everything looks good except for the last select value (VolumeOfPayments) which is duplicating values even though the other output's before it are different (SubserviceName/SubserviceNumber/Map). How do i get that select to be distinct per the above fields?
The select is below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                   tctc_cntipcli as "TypeOfContract" ,
                   texe_cncclipu as "ContractNumber",
                   tctc_cndocidc as "ClientName",
                   tsrv_cndesser as "ServiceName",
                   texe_cnfuncid as "ServiceNumber",
                   tsrs_cnsubsdc as "SubserviceName",
                   texe_cnsubser as "SubserviceNumber",
                   tmap_cndesc   as "Map",
        (
        SELECT DECODE(to_char(count(tlof_cnlofrid)), '0', 'NA', COUNT(TLOF_CNLOFRID))
        from service.kndtlof
        where tlof_cncclipu = texe_cncclipu
        and tlof_cnservic = texe_cnfuncid
        and tlof_cnsubser = texe_cnsubser
        and tlof_cnfhalta > trunc (sysdate, 'mm')
       ) as "VolumeOfFilesMessages",

                    (select DECODE(to_char(count(it.int_tran_id)), '0','NA', COUNT(IT.INT_TRAN_ID))
                                       from internal_transactions it, status ss, app_data ad -- TRANSACTIONS DB CALL, WHICH HOLDS TRANSACTION INFO FOR CONTRACTS IN THE SERVICS DB
                                       where it.debit_acct IN (select distinct ke.texe_cnasupro
                                                                from service.kndtexe ke -- CALL TO SERVICES DB WHICH HOLDS CONTRACT LEVEL INFO, OR THE SELECT VALUES ABOVE
                                                                where (
                                                                (texe_cnfuncid = '3001' and texe_cnsubser = 'W1')
                                                                or
                                                                (texe_cnfuncid = '3085' and texe_cnsubser LIKE ('I%'))
                                                                       )
                                                                --and texe_cncclipu = tctc_cncclipu
                                                                --and texe_cnfuncid = tsrv_cncveser
                                                                --and texe_cnfuncid = tsrs_cncveser
                                                                --and texe_cnsubser = tsrs_cnsubser
                                                                --and texe_cncclipu = tscm_cncontra
                                                                --and texe_cnfuncid = tscm_cnservic
                                                                --and texe_cnsubser = tscm_cnsubser
                                                                --and tscm_cnmapco  = tmap_cnmapco
                                                                --and tscm_cnservic = tmap_cnservic
                                                                )
                                      and it.entry_timestamp > trunc (sysdate, 'mm')
                                      and it.int_tran_id = ss.int_tran_id
                                      and ss.stage in ('ACHPayment_Confirmed', 'HIFV5_FTRINF', 'Payment_HIFV5_FTRINF', 'HIFV4')
                                      and it.int_tran_id = ad.int_tran_id
                                      and ( 
                                            (ad.add_info_table ='Wire' /*and KE.texe_cnfuncid = '3001' AND TEXE_CNSUBSER = 'W1'*/)
                                            or
                                            (ad.add_info_table = 'ACH' and texe_cnfuncid = '3085' AND TEXE_CNSUBSER LIKE ('I%'))
                                          )
                                      ) as "VolumeOfPayments"                       

                          from service.kndtctc, service.kndtexe, service.kndtscm, service.kndtsrv, service.kndtsrs, service.kndtmap
                          where tctc_cncclipu = texe_cncclipu
                          and texe_cnfuncid = tsrv_cncveser
                          and texe_cnfuncid = tsrs_cncveser
                          and texe_cnsubser = tsrs_cnsubser
                          and texe_cncclipu = tscm_cncontra
                          and tscm_cnmapco = tmap_cnmapco
                          and tscm_cnservic = tsrv_cncveser
                          and tscm_cnsubser = tsrs_cnsubser
                          and tctc_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and texe_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and tsrv_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and tsrs_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and tscm_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          and tmap_cnestado in ('01', '03')
                          AND TEXE_CNCCLIPU = '50009823'
                          AND TEXE_CNFUNCID = '3085'
                          order by texe_cncclipu
      ;
```

And the output is :[image: Output]

Thanks for your time...

[image: OUTPUT 2]

Comment: And you are certain these aren't the values you are looking for right?

Comment: yes sir ... the volume that is duplicating depends on the mailbox (subservice) it gets dropped into and those are different.

Comment: It might be a group by issue? As if it finds multiple results("11") to the query

Comment: i tried it with a group by clause already, same output.

Comment: What else have you tried unsuccessfully? From what I can see, that last column isn't tied in with any outside values, that might explain it?

Comment: ive tried playing around with how to link that select to the main select. for example, that value would only be populated for the I's and not the O's. The only db values to link the two databases for the correct info are the "where" clause  for the acct# and the add_info_table field from one db to its corresponding texe_cnfuncid in the other db(and that is only by knowing this texe_cnfuncid relates to that add_info_table). as you can see i commented out some and clauses while testing, but even with those in tact its doing the same.

Comment: where is your joining condition, which joins your main query and "VolumeOfPayments" subquery?

Comment: the part that is commented out in the subquery

Comment: can anyone lead me in the right direction please?

Comment: This is a really complex problem with no real way for us to test it.  Could you maybe provide more data samples? (i.e. what is returned when you change the conditions for the sub query)

Comment: Yes, Le W please see the second output image i have attached...

Comment: Are the other columns values fine?

Comment: yes they are correct.

Comment: Would 14 perhaps be the total of all payments for that client?

Comment: appears to be the case...

Comment: There is actually no line that specifies into which sub service the transaction went, so as long as it finds at least one, it just counts all of them and displays the total, this is due to not having specified in the where  clause anything that links the actual transaction to a specific sub service.

Comment: So how would that where clause look with your recommendation?

Comment: Is there anything like a service name or sub service name in either internal-Transaction, status or app_data?

Comment: nope those reside in the services db, ie the one that house the kndtexe, kndtctc tables etc which the main select is based on

Comment: Then is there no way to know where the transaction came from?

Comment: the transaction db only holds information in the account level(per transaction). The other clause I have included in the "and" with the ad.add_info_table (tran db) with the texe_cnfuncid (serv db) is the farthest we can take the link. No subservices whatsoever in the tran db.

Comment: Then this is quite problematic as there is no way to say a certain transaction has been made by that service, so the only thing you can actually count are the total amount of transaction for that client like it is doing currently.